# Ability to add search keyword to article - SFCC

Tags: commerce-cloud

is there a way to add keyword search so products and articles will appear as a result at the same time?

For example, black tea products will appear when a customer search for 'black tea', however we also have an article about 'benefits of black tea'. Is there a way to have both products and article appear after customer search the keywords 'black tea'?

In the screenshot attached only black tea product come up. Article is 0. Do I need to set up keywords for article separately?

Comment: what screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Commerce Cloud B2C provides (both in search results & suggestions) the possibility to show content (Assets & Page Designer Pages).

You need to mark these items as "searchable" before they begin to show up.

Documentation for Search Indexes: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/search_and_navigation/b2c_search_indexes.html